# Known function in ODE solvers

Tags: matlab, ode

I'm new in Matlab, so sorry for asking a banal and probably already answered question, but I wasn't able to solve it.

I have this ODE to solve

g''(x)+f(x)g'(x)

with g(0)=0 and g'(0)=0.5

f(x) is a known vector, so I tried

```
xspan = linspace(0,10,100);
y0 = [0,0.5];
%f=f(xspan), known function, for example f=1./xspan;
[x,y] = ode45('odefun',xspan,y0);
```

and for `odefun`

```
function dy=odefun(x,y)

global f  

dy(1) = y(2);
dy(2) = -f.*y(2);

dy    = dy(:);
end
```

Of course it doesn't work. How can I pass the values of vector `f` to the solver?

EDIT

Thanks for help, but this is not working for me. Maybe I have an old Matlab version (7.11.0 (R2010B))? I tried to do as you told, but this is what I get in command window

```
???  In an assignment  A(I) = B, the number of elements in B and
 I must be the same.

Error in ==> odefun at 3
dy(2) = -f.*y(2);

Error in ==> @(x,y)odefun(x,y,f)


Error in ==> odearguments at 109
f0 = feval(ode,t0,y0,args{:});   % ODE15I sets args{1} to yp0.

Error in ==> ode45 at 173
[neq, tspan, ntspan, next, t0, tfinal, tdir, y0, f0, odeArgs, odeFcn, ...

Error in ==> trying at 7
[x,y] = ode45(fun,xspan,y0);
```

This is the code trying.m

```
xspan=linspace(0,10,100);
y0=[0 0.5];
f=1./xspan;
[x,y] = ode45(@(x,y)odefun(x,y,f),xspan,y0);
```

and the odefun

```
function dy=odefun(x,y,f)
dy(1) = y(2);
dy(2) = -f.*y(2);
dy    = dy(:);
end
```

Comment: Re: your edit (a new question): You still have to satisfy all of the usual rules for writing ODE functions. It looks like you're passing in a vector for `f` and then trying to set it equal to a single element of `dy`: `dy(2) = -f.*y(2);`. `dy(2) = -f(1).*y(2);` or `dy(2) = -f(end).*y(2);` would work. Are you possibly trying to extract the step size, `dt` that `ode45` is using on each time step to use it in `odefun`? If so, this approach won't work.

Comment: I didn't think about that, f is a vector and I can't do that of course. Sorry for the mistake. By the way I don't want to do f(1)*y(2) or f(end), I need f to be evaluated at every step used in the ode45 solver. So, should I find the step size, as suggested, and then interpolate the f at those steps? How could I do that? Really thank you for your help!

Comment: There is no way to get the step sizes that `ode45` is using internally while it runs (`xspan` is only the set of output points not necessarily the true steps taken by the solver – [my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21861868/2278029) might help a bit). You can get the independent variable `x`, but not the step size. An ODE shouldn't be a function of step size to begin with, only the current independent and dependent variables and any parameters. You may be trying something numerically and mathematically inadvisable.

Comment: In the truth I don't need to know the step sizes of the ode45, I need to solve the differential equation g''(x)+f(x)g'(x)=0, and I didnt know how the pass the values of the f(x) (that I evaluated before). I understand that the xspan vector does not represent the true steps used by the ode45, but I needed the f(x) to be evaluated at those steps to solve the equation above, for this I thought about interpolation. So, is there no way I can do this? If I can get the independent variable x, so could I use interpolation to get f(x) values for each 'x' of the ode? If not, is there no way to solve it?

Comment: The first input to your `odefun` is `x`.

Comment: If you could help me with the code I would apprecciate, because as I told you I'm not very used with programming. So how can I get the values of f(x) knowing f(xspan)?

Comment: This is really a separate question from the original one that you asked. Also, you haven't defined your function `f` as a function. If f(x) is a constant function that doesn't actually depend `x` then you can pass in a scalar or vector. Otherwise you need to pass in a function (i.e., a function handle) that takes `x` as an argument. You need to define exactly what `f` is and ask a new specific question related to this. Provide any error messages that you get for what you're trying, etc.

Comment: f(x) is a function get from the solution fo another ode, so I know it at each xspan, even if I don't know its analitical expression. If you want I asked a related question here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23737271/how-to-get-values-by-interpolation-of-a-function-fx-not-knowing-its-analit) thanks for help

Comment: It was very easy. In the way I put in the answer the code works, but why if `f` is a vector, and I set it equal to a single element, as we observed above? It works and it's good for me , but I can't get it :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're using [`global`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/global.html) variables incorrectly (`f` needs to be declared `global` in your main function as well), but you shouldn't be using globals to begin with. [You should rarely, if ever, use globals.](http://blogs.mathworks.com/videos/2010/03/08/top-10-matlab-code-practices-that-make-me-cry/) You should also specify your integration function, `odefun`, as an [anonymous function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html) rather than a string in modern Matlab. Here is how you can modify your code to fix these issues:

```
...
f = ...
[x,y] = ode45(@(x,y)odefun(x,y,f),xspan,y0);
```

And your integration function, which can be a [sub-function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/local-functions.html) or in a separate file, just needs to take an extra argument for the parameter `f`:

```
function dy=odefun(x,y,f)
dy(1) = y(2);
dy(2) = -f.*y(2);
dy    = dy(:);
```

The methods should also be faster than using strings and globals. The code `@(x,y)odefun(x,y,f)` creates an anonymous function of `x` and `y` (`ode45` expects a function that takes exactly two inputs) that captures the value of `f` from the current scope. This is also referred to as a [closure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_programming%29) in computer science. You can equivalently create a function handle and pass that in:

```
...
f = ...
fun = @(x,y)odefun(x,y,f)
[x,y] = ode45(fun,xspan,y0);
```

See also [this article on parametrizing functions](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/parameterizing-functions.html) from The MathWorks for more information on this general technique.

Comment: Thanks for interest, but I've still got problems. I edited, the question, if you could I would appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

I solved it, it was not so difficult, I just needed to interpolate the f at each value of the independent variable x. In this way the code works

```
function dy=odefun(x,y,f,xspan)
f=interp1(xspan,f,x);
dy(1) = y(2);
dy(2) = -f.*y(2);
dy    = dy(:);
end
```