# Comparison of odeint's runge_kutta4 with Matlab's ode45

Tags: c++, matlab, boost, numerical-integration, odeint

I would like to use `runge_kutta4` method in the [odeint C++ library](http://headmyshoulder.github.io/odeint-v2/). I've solved the problem in Matlab. My following code in Matlab to solve `x'' = -x - g*x'`, with initial values `x1 = 1`, `x2 = 0`, is as follows

`main.m`

```
clear all
clc
t = 0:0.1:10;
x0 = [1; 0];
[t, x] = ode45('ODESolver', t, x0);
plot(t, x(:,1));
title('Position');
xlabel('time (sec)');
ylabel('x(t)');
```

`ODESolver.m`

```
function dx = ODESolver(t, x)
dx = zeros(2,1);
g  = 0.15;
dx(1) =  x(2);
dx(2) = -x(1) - g*x(2);
end
```

I've installed the odeint Library. My code for using `runge_kutta4` is as follows

```
#include <iostream>

#include <boost/numeric/odeint.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace boost::numeric::odeint;

/* The type of container used to hold the state vector */
typedef std::vector< double > state_type;

const double gam = 0.15;

/* The rhs of x' = f(x) */
void lorenz( const state_type &x , state_type &dx ,  double t )
{
    dx[0] =  x[1];
    dx[1] = -x[0] - gam*x[1];
}


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    const double dt = 0.1;
    runge_kutta_dopri5<state_type> stepper;
    state_type x(2);
    x[0] = 1.0;
    x[1] = 0.0;


   double t = 0.0;
   cout << x[0] << endl;
   for ( size_t i(0); i <= 100; ++i){
       stepper.do_step(lorenz, x , t, dt );
       t += dt;
       cout << x[0] << endl;
   }


    return 0;
}
```

The result is in the following picture
[image]

My question is why the result varies? Is there something wrong with my C++ code?

These are the first values of both methods

```
Matlab    C++
-----------------
1.0000    0.9950
0.9950    0.9803
0.9803    0.9560
0.9560    0.9226
0.9226    0.8806
0.8806    0.8304
0.8304    0.7728
0.7728    0.7084
0.7083    0.6379
```

---

Update:

The problem is that I forgot to include the initial value in my C++ code. Thanks for @horchler for noticing it. After including the proper values and using `runge_kutta_dopri5` as @horchler suggested, the result is

```
Matlab    C++
-----------------
1.0000    1.0000
0.9950    0.9950
0.9803    0.9803
0.9560    0.9560
0.9226    0.9226
0.8806    0.8806
0.8304    0.8304
0.7728    0.7728
0.7083    0.7084
```

I've updated the code to reflect these modifications.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `runge_kutta4` stepper in odeint is nothing like Matlab's [`ode45`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ode45.html), which is an adaptive scheme based on the [Dormand-Prince](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dormand-Prince_method) method. To replicate Matlab's results, you should probably try the [`runge_kutta_dopri5`](http://headmyshoulder.github.io/odeint-v2/doc/boost_numeric_odeint/odeint_in_detail/steppers.html#boost_numeric_odeint.odeint_in_detail.steppers.stepper_overview) stepper. Also, make sure that your C++ code uses the same absolute and relative tolerances as `ode45` (defaults are `1e-6` and `1e-3`, respectively). Lastly, it looks like you may not be saving/printing your initial condition in your C++ results.

If you're confused at why `ode45` is not taking fixed steps even though you specified `t = 0:0.1:10;`, see [my detailed answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21861868/2278029).

If you must use the fixed step`runge_kutta4` stepper, then you'll need to reduce the integration step-size in your C++ code to match Matlab's output.

Comment: +1 Not too long ago, Cleve Moler wrote a couple of nice blog posts about ODE solvers in MATLAB: http://blogs.mathworks.com/cleve/2014/05/12/ordinary-differential-equation-suite/, http://blogs.mathworks.com/cleve/2014/05/26/ordinary-differential-equation-solvers-ode23-and-ode45/, http://blogs.mathworks.com/cleve/2014/06/09/ordinary-differential-equations-stiffness/

Comment: I second @Amro's suggestion. Highly recommended and helpful even if you don't use Matlab. The [Cleve's Corner blog](http://blogs.mathworks.com/cleve/) is excellent reading.

Comment: @horchler, than you so much for being helpful and informative. I found the problem. I didn't include the initial value in my plotting for C++. This did the trick. The results are now matching perfectly.

Comment: @horchler, in your link, `diff(sol.x)` what is exactly this x? I'm getting errors.

Comment: "The results are now matching perfectly." - they might be closer, but they won't match "perfectly" unless you change steppers. If you try to integrate a more complex and stiffer system, the differences will become more visually apparent.

Comment: Re: `diff(sol.x)`. Read the documentation for `ode45`. If just one output is returned, it will be a `struct` (here called `sol`) containing the solution at the actual integration points, as opposed to the dense interpolated points when you return the normal two output vectors. `sol.x` is the independent variable for the integration (usually time) – it is not the `x` in your ODE function, but `t`. `diff` calculates the difference between each value in the `sol.x` vector to find the actual variable step sizes the solver used.

Answer (score 4):

The Matlab ode45 function already includes error control and I think also interpolation (dense output). to compare with boost.odeint you should use the same functionality there. Boost.odeint provides `integrate` functions that perform step-size control and dense output if the used stepper algorithm provides this functionality. The following code piece shows how you this is used with the default error control parameters from Matlab given by horchler:

```
#include <boost/numeric/odeint.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace boost::numeric::odeint;

/* The type of container used to hold the state vector */
typedef std::vector< double > state_type;

const double gam = 0.15;

/* The rhs of x' = f(x) */
void damped_osc( const state_type &x , state_type &dx , const double t )
{
    dx[0] =  x[1];
    dx[1] = -x[0] - gam*x[1];
}

void print( const state_type &x, const double t )
{
    cout << x[0] << endl;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    cout.precision(16);  // full precision output
    const double dt = 0.1;
    typedef runge_kutta_dopri5<state_type> stepper_type;
    state_type x(2);
    x[0] = 1.0;
    x[1] = 0.0;

    integrate_const(make_dense_output<stepper_type>( 1E-6, 1E-3 ),
                    damped_osc, x, 0.0, 10.0, dt , print);

    return 0;
}
```

Please note that the results might still not be *exactly* the same (as in all 16 digits) because the error control in Boost.odeint might not be impemented *exactly* as in Matlab's ode45.