# Calling ODE solver (odeint) within c++ class

Tags: c++, pointers, member, ode, odeint

I need to solve ODE equations set with odeint library. "main.cpp" file is only to call calculation (it will be extended later, here simple version to keep code clean)

`main.cpp`

```
#include "calc.h"

int main()
{
    calc c;
    c.startC();
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the calc header, starC(); is set public.
`calc.h`

```
#ifndef MAIN_H
#define MAIN_H

#include <iostream>
#include <boost/numeric/odeint.hpp>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace boost::numeric::odeint;

typedef std::vector< double > vector_type;

class calc
{
public:
    int main();
    void startC();
private:
    void solveODE(const vector_type &y , vector_type &ODE , const double t );
    void printR();

};

#endif // MAIN_H
```

Here is the main calculation part. Also here the error occurs:
`calc.cpp`

```
include <iostream>

#include <boost/numeric/odeint.hpp>
#include <math.h>

#include "calc.h"

using namespace std;
using namespace boost::numeric::odeint;

const double g = 0.15;


void calc::solveO( const vector_type &y , vector_type &ODE , const double t )
{
    dy[0] =  y[1];
    dy[1] = -y[0] - g*y[1];
}

void calc::printR(const vector_type &y, const double t)
{
    cout << t << endl;
    cout << y[0] << endl;
}

void calc::startC()
{
    const double dt = 0.1;
    typedef runge_kutta_dopri5<vector_type> stepper_type;
    vector_type y(2);
    //Initial conditins
    y[0]=   1.0;
    y[1]=   0.0;


    //Initializing of ODE solver
    integrate_const(make_dense_output<stepper_type>( 1E-12, 1E-6 ), 
                    this->*solveO, y, 0.0, 1.0, dt , printResults); //ERROR HERE
}

int calc::main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

This operation ends with error on the level of "Initializing of ODE solver" with:

```
'((calc*)this)->calc::solveO' cannot be used as a member pointer,
since it is of type '<unresolved overloaded function type>'
```

What's wrong with this call:

```
this->*solveO
```

And what's the correct way to call solveO inside "integrate_const"?

**Edit:**
Thanks to the help of @tobi303 and @rbelli it now works. Here I post sum-up, TL:DR explanation:

The easiest solution is to make solveO and printR free function and call:

```
integrate_const(make_dense_output<stepper_type>( 1E-12, 1E-6 ), solveO, y, 0.0, 1.0, dt , printR);
```

Comment: Instead of this->*solve (as explained bellow by tobi303) you can use boost::bind(this, &calc::solveO, _1, _2, _3), or you can use a lambda function like [this](const vector_type &y , vector_type &ODE , const double t){this->solveO(y, ODE, t);} as the  integrate_const accept functors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `integrate_const` takes a function pointer you cannot pass a member function pointer. Member function pointers are different from function pointers, because they implicitly need `this` as argument.

As you dont use any members of the class inside `solveO` you can simply make it a free function:

```
void solveO( const vector_type &y , vector_type &ODE , const double t )
{
    dy[0] =  y[1];
    dy[1] = -y[0] - g*y[1];
}
```

Comment: It explains a bit, but still doesn't point the correct call. I'm not very experienced in c++. I tried solutions suggested by @rbelli:

1.boost::bind fails: `"'bind' is not a member of 'boost'"`

2. Seems to interferes with integrate_const: `"must use '.*' or '->*' to call pointer-to-member function"`

Comment: @Karls hope this wont sound rude: experienced or not, you need to rtfm. I tried to look up what parameters `integreate_const` takes, but it is heavily templated, so I would also have to read their manual to know what can be passed. If you are lucky you can pass a functor or lambda. In any case I would stay away from `bind`, but thats just my personal preference

Comment: it's not about wrong parameters, so you hurried a little wit rtfm. I know how to execute integreate_const. Look here (last answer): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26747492/comparison-of-odeints-runge-kutta4-with-matlabs-ode45
If I code all one file like in this example, it works. The problems start when I use a class as I presented in OP. And  for some reasons I need it in this form, as it will be part of bigger program. Do you understand now where is the real problem?

Comment: @Karls if it is not about parameters then what is it about? You definitely cannot pass a member function pointer without also passing an instance. I dont know what parameters you can pass to `integrate_const`, otherwise I could tell you how to solve it. Btw dont try to be javaish. Not everything has to be in a class, just because classes are cool....

Comment: @Karls  ...Anyhow there is no good reason why the function you pass must be a member function. You dont even use any members of the class.

Comment: I tried to use it as free function (basing on your edited answer).
And it still fails somwhere:
call: `integrate_const(make_dense_output<stepper_type>( 1E-12, 1E-6 ), solveO, y, 0.0, 1.0, dt , printR)` ends again with `must use '.*' or '->*' to call pointer-to-member function`

Comment: @Karls `printR` is a member function, and the same is true for that aswell: No reason to make it member of a class, it uses parameters passed to it and nothing else

Comment: @Karls there is no advantage of a function being a member function as opposed to being a free function. In fact the lesser member function a class has the better it is. You can be happy for every function that does not need to be member of a class, because it makes your code simpler